# Test arguments in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Is it possible to check what arguments is being passed to a method when testing with rspec?

If I for i.e want to test class A, inside class A i call class B, B is already tested.
The only thing I want to test is the ingoing arguments to B.

```
class A
  def method
    number = 10
    B.calling(number)
  end
end

class B
  def self.calling(argument)
    # This code in this class is already testet
  end
end
```

How do I test the ingoing arguments to B.calling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using rspec mock/stubs try

```
B.should_receive(calling).with(10)
```

http://kerryb.github.com/iprug-rspec-presentation/ covers a lot of basic usage, or see the docs or rspec book.

Comment: should_receive is an extension to object (I think) so it works on classes and instances just the same. It works by stubbing out the method with some code that tracks whether it's called or not. So you'd set up your object instance and call should receive on that in the same way. Can also look at different kinds of matchers (e.g. argument is a string, integer, even number, …), times called, ordering of different calls to the same method on the same object, etc.

Comment: I think to test `calling` on an instance you would need to set the `should_receive` on an instance of that class. You might also be interested in [mock_model and stub_model](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-9/docs/mocks)